# How to escape back-tics surrounded by single quotes?

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have this handy script to print a table that displays name, type, and id of the instances that is running.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --filters "Name=instance-state-code,Values=16" \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Tags[?Key==`Name`]|[0].Value, InstanceType, InstanceId]' \
    --output table
```

`------------------------------------------------
 |              DescribeInstances              |
 +--------+------------+-----------------------+
 |  Jessie|  t2.micro  |  i-0a67ee24b226463e9  |
 +--------+------------+-----------------------+`

I try to add this command to my zshrc as an alias/function, but I just can't find a way to escape the back-tics that surround the last occurrence of "Name". Please note that the back-tics are surrounded by single quotes in this case. Thanks for helping.

Comment: How are you trying to add it to your zshrc file?

Comment: @duskwuff I intend to add it as an alias or function(just updated the question).

Comment: Can you give an example of what you tried?

Comment: Try replacing the single quotes `'` with double quotes `"` and the backticks with single quotes `'`.  I think the query will still work.

Comment: It'll work fine in a function exactly as-is.

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60688/how-to-defer-variable-expansion), it explains how to defer the variable expansion. I think the best way is to use a function to wrap your command, and the variables in the back-tic surrounded word will be evaluated when the command is executed, not as it is interpreted.